# jQuery function working in test page but not the whole website

Tags: jquery

So jQuery is getting the best of me again :(

I was wondering if any of you could help me figure out why a certain jQuery function I created wont work in one environment but does in another.

```
$("#processor li").click(function() {
    $("#processor li").removeClass("active-line");
    $(this).addClass("active-line");
});
```

This is the HTML that the above function works from

```
<ul id="processor">
    <li>
        <input id="cpu-1" type="radio" value="1" name="cpu">
        <label for="cpu-1">Intel&reg; Core&trade; i3 2100 3.1GHz</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So far I have tested this in a separate file in which it worked, but when imported back into the website the functionality stopped. I tested the code in the test page with `$(document).ready(function() {` and without and both ways worked fine and have tested the same in the whole website and it still did not help the situation.

I have also tried doing very absolute paths when calling the element in the jQuery function and not and still it does not work in the website.

So I hope someone out there can help me figure out why the function will not work in the full website.

Thanks in advance,

Dan.

Comment: Is the content being gained via ajax? Then you would have to use .live('click', function() { instead of .click(function() {

Comment: Yes the data comes through via ajax, I shall try your suggestion and let you know, Thank you.

Comment: Nothing seems wrong... But you could do $("#processor li.active-line").removeClass("active-line"); so it only remove the class on LI's that actually have it already :)

Comment: If the code works on a test page, but not in production, it must have something to do with the production environment. So, posting working code doesn't really help solve the problem, show some of the production setup, e.g. the HTML head. Also give some debug information if possible: Did you check that the script where the click listener is registered is really executed?

Comment: Works perfectly :) thank you very much I shall go read up on .live now.

Comment: @Marco Johannesen, Yeah I suppose that would tidy up the script a bit and make it more efficient :) cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would have to use

```
.live('click', function() {
```

instead of

```
.click(function() {
```

if the content comes via ajax

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you have a logical problem:

```
$("#processor li").removeClass("active-line"); == $(this).removeClass("active-line");
```

in that case, because you only have one "li Tag".

In other words, when you click you are always adding class "active-line"

Comment: i think the behaviour he has is expected. in the live page he will have more li-items for sure. if you think about it you know what he wants to achieve

Comment: Sorry, mu posted code was missing the other <li>'s there are plenty, I just wanted to show a cut down version of the code to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for differences between your website and the separate page,look for:

- More than one #processor element, because no two elements can have the same id
- Check for differences in the number of li elements
- Check for other scripts running which can affect these elements(probably by checking the DOM variables)
- Any css styles which can prevent you from clicking on the element such as a div ontop of them